# SQL Server speed up query with not in

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have a table called `sales` with the following few columns:

```
salesno (PK, char(25))
advanceno (char(15), not null)
```

Now I want to select all the rows where `salesno` is not in `advanceno`:

```
SELECT salesno 
FROM sales 
WHERE salesno NOT IN (SELECT advanceno FROM sales)
```

The query is slow because the sales table has hundred thousands of rows.

I did this, and it is very fast:

```
SELECT salesno 
FROM sales 
WHERE salesno NOT IN ('000008360', '000008361', '000008362', '000008363', '000008364')
```

How can I optimise the query?

Comment: Joins are typically faster than where limits.

Comment: Does the sales table have any indexes on it?

Comment: When was the last time that stats were updated? Has it been a while? Have a significant # of rows been added since?

Comment: No index, only salesno is the primary key.

Comment: xQbert, Is this fact or your opinion? There will be a join regardless. The join algorithm chosen by the optimizer is what is in question. Many would say a NOT EXISTS or, if there will not be NULLS, a NOT IN would be the best option. Typically, a LEFT JOIN will be a complete join, returning all matching rows (including duplicates) and then filtering. A NOT EXISTS or NOT IN will more likely be an anti-semi join (partial join), not joining all rows but simply checking for absence of existence. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @sales as Table (salesno char(25)
,advanceno char(15) not null)

INSERT INTO @sales(salesno,advanceno)
SELECT '000008360','000008360' UNION ALL
SELECT '000008361','000008362' UNION ALL
SELECT '000008362','000008364' 

SELECT  s.salesno 
FROM    @sales s 
LEFT JOIN @sales a ON a.advanceno = s.salesno
WHERE   a.advanceno IS NULL
```

In your example, try this

```
SELECT  s.salesno 
FROM    sales s 
LEFT JOIN sales a ON a.advanceno = s.salesno
WHERE   a.advanceno IS NULL
```

Comment: It is slower then the not in method.

Comment: Surprisingly, when I indexed advanceno, it is very fast.

Comment: @Lelvin: that's **not** surprising at all !

Comment: @marc_s at least I am surprise. I am upbeat!!